# How to use lodash _.find to return value even if iterating over numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

so I have this function:

```
var res = _.find(table_campaign_boards().getAllPrimaryKeys(), (campaign_board_id,v) => {
            var recCampaignTimeline = table_campaign_boards().getRec(campaign_board_id);
            if (recCampaignTimeline.campaign_id == i_campaign_id) {
                var board_id = recCampaignTimeline['board_id']
                return table_boards().getRec(board_id);
            }
        });
```

And when a match is found, I get back the index since `table_campaign_boards().getAllPrimaryKeys` returns a list of numbers. How do I have _.find, find and stop on first value, and return the object found and not the index it found. Sure I can use `for` loop and break, but would rather use lodash as I get both key / value.

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Why do you loop on `Primary keys`?

Comment: getAllPrimaryKeys() is the interface I get from the lib I use,  to get all indexes

Comment: But if that returns a list of numbers, you only could find and return a number. What's `table_campaign_boards()`? Why don't you loop on it?

Comment: As @AlessandroMaglioccola pointed out, if `table_campaign_boards()` returns an Iterable, you can simply use `find` on its result, rather than using `getAllPrimaryKeys()`. Also, please note that `find()` invokes its predicate with the args `(value, index, collection)`--your use of `k, campaign_board_id` above implies that you're treating the first argument as the key and the second as the value, which is reversed.

Comment: yes I need to fix the order tx of the sample ```k``` args, however I do have to call getAllPrimaryKeys as it goes out and does some sever calls and gets data behind the scenes, so the question remains, no way of getting find to return the value as its the inner function ```table_campaign_boards()``` that returns the data?